# Quantum cup product and Dolbeault cohomology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, hodge-theory, gromov-witten-theory, quantum-cohomology

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety over $\mathbb{C}$. We consider the small quantum cup product $\star$ on the deRham cohomology ring $\displaystyle H^*(X;\mathbb{C})=\bigoplus_{p,q}H^{p,q}(X)$. Let $H^{(i)}$ denote $\displaystyle\bigoplus_{p-q=i}H^{p,q}(X)$.

In [''Gamma Conjecture via Mirror Symmetry''](https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.00719), Galkin and Iritani claimed in the Appendix that $H^{(i)}\star H^{(j)}\subseteq H^{(i+j)}$ in order to draw a conclusion about the spectrum of the operator $c_1(X)\star$ acting on various subspaces of $H^*(X)$. They said this claim follows from the motivic axiom of the Gromov Witten theory. How should one argue following this line?

Thanks.

Remark: If $X$ is convex, then $\overline{\cal M}_{0,3}(X,\beta)$ is a smooth projective variety so the claim should be obvious. But in general we have to use virtual fundamental cycle to define $\star$. I don't know what we should do then.